# Javascript - Sum table column with decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script which calculating all column values in table, but now the script gets only full number, not calculating decimal, so if I have:

column1 ------- column2

some text ----- 10.2

other text ------ 3.4

textt ------------- 20.9

I am getting just 33 not 34.5

My code:

```
var tds = document.getElementById('vinyle').getElementsByTagName('td');
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
    if (tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
         sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
    }
}

document.getElementById('vinyle').innerHTML += '<tr class="sum"><td>' + sum + '</td></tr>';
```

How to edit this to start calculating with decimals?

Comment: What could the `Int` in `parseInt` possibly stand for? Might there exist a similar method for _floats_ …?

Comment: Try `parseFloat(tds[i].innerHTML).toFixed(2)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [parseFloat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

```
var tds = document.getElementById('vinyle').getElementsByTagName('td');
                var sum = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
                    if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
                        sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseFloat(tds[i].innerHTML);
                    }
                }


                document.getElementById('vinyle').innerHTML += '<tr class="sum"><td>' + sum.toFixed(2) + '</td></tr>';
```

```js
var tds= ['36.2','56.2'];

                var sum = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {

                        sum += isNaN(tds[i]) ? 0 : parseFloat(tds[i]);
                    
                }


                document.getElementById('vinyle').innerHTML += '<tr class="sum"><td>' + sum.toFixed(2) + '</td></tr>';
```

```html
<div id="vinyle"></div>
```

Comment: With this code the result of 36.2 and 56.2 is 036.2056.20, so something went wrong :/

Comment: i updated my answer please check now. remove toFixed and try.

Comment: Okay, now it works :) But I have new problem, for example, in 8 rows there is number 3.8, so 3.8 * 8 = 30,4, but the script gives me weird 30.400000000000002, why do I get this result?

Comment: use toFixed for sum varuiable. i have updated my answer check now.  document.getElementById('vinyle').innerHTML += '<tr class="sum"><td>' + sum.toFixed(2) + '</td></tr>';

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Use parseFloat instead of parseInt.